# How to download a specific package beforehand, so that I can install this after setting up Ubuntu without having an internet connection?

Tags: installation, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

I am about to format my computer and install Ubuntu. This particular computer is the local server that provides internet to all machines in our network. I will be installing Ubuntu 12.04 Server Edition. However, for my internet to work I need a particular package, which is not included in the regular list of packages that are included in the installation. This is the [Madwimax](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/madwimax) package.

After I install Ubuntu, what is the proper way to install Madwimax, without some manual install (i.e. using apt-get, but without having internet)? Currently I still have internet so I can go and download certain packages, but I'm just not sure what and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually several options. I believe one of these should work for you:

[AptGet/Offline from help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository)

[AptMedium from debian.org](http://wiki.debian.org/AptMedium)

[apt-offline from debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/sid/apt-offline)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Keryx - http://keryxproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can download the .deb file, copy it to usb stick (or something like that) and after the setup is done just install it via "sudo dpkg -i xxx".

For that to work you need all dependencies though!

Answer (score 1):

This is your answer : http://ershadk.com/blog/2010/06/13/how-to-download-deb-packages-for-offline-installation-2/